# Are all of zero() in chrono the same thing

Tags: c++, c++11, c++-chrono

I've found many `zero()` in the namespace `std::chrono`:

```
std::chrono::system_clock::duration::zero();
std::chrono::minutes::zero();
std::chrono::seconds::zero();
std::chrono::milliseconds::zero();
...
```

Are they all the same thing?

I'm coding with `std::chrono` and I have many variables whose types are `std::chrono::seconds`, `std::chrono::milliseconds`. If I want to check if a variable is zero or not, which one should I use?

```
std::chrono::seconds start = std::chrono::duration_cast<T>(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()); // get current time
// something
std::chrono::seconds end = std::chrono::duration_cast<T>(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()); // get current time
if (end - start == 0) // std::chrono::system_clock::duration::zero()? std::seconds::zero()? std::milliseconds::zero()?
{
    // something
}
```

In this `if` condition, which kind of zero should I use? Or I can use anyone because they are exactly the same? You may want to say `end == start` works too, I can live with that but I still want to know if all of these zeros are the same thing.

Comment: I'd recommend keeping your time points `start` and `end` as their proper type instead of immediately converting them to durations. It's misleading having variables called `start` and `end` that are actually durations, and you'll get a duration anyway when you subtract them.

Comment: @chris  In my real case, `start` and `end` have been assigned with time duration... Well, in fact here is the reason: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68406846/what-is-the-proper-way-to-process-milliseconds-in-c11.

Comment: @chris In my project, there are many variables about time, which stored the time of some kinds of event happening, such as the time of a video starting, the time of a radio starting, etc. I've googled a lot and it seems that using time duration, instead of using time point is suggested...

Comment: I don't really buy that. I agree wholeheartedly with Howard's answer in the linked question that you're throwing away [free] type safety by storing time points as durations. You're also making readers of the code stop to wonder why you went out of your way to convert. If you need these as durations, the variable names had better be something that actually means a duration as well. Based on the information given, you have actual points in time that you want to store and there's a type (or a related set of types) that does exactly that while being clear and preventing some logical mistakes.

Comment: @chris  hmm, let me reconsider...

Comment: FWIW, said answer is by the person who created this library. He designed this type safety to be the foundation of the library, and it comes across clearly as when you have to explicitly say something as nonsensical as `time_since_epoch` to do something where the time since the epoch is irrelevant. The library certainly provides escape hatches for those times where you really need out, but it's best to work _with_ it unless you cannot.

Comment: @chris He's the author? Sorry I'm blind. time_point vs time_duration, yeah, each of them has its own role and own job. You are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the `seconds`, `milliseconds` etc are typedefs of the duration type with different ratios:

```
...
std::chrono::milliseconds   duration</*signed integer type of at least 45 bits*/, std::milli>
std::chrono::seconds    duration</*signed integer type of at least 35 bits*/>
std::chrono::minutes    duration</*signed integer type of at least 29 bits*/, std::ratio<60>>
std::chrono::hours  duration</*signed integer type of at least 23 bits*/, std::ratio<3600>>
...
```

[See here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration)

So when you call the function `zero` on this type, it produces the value in the form of this type, but it calls the same function implementation ([`std::chrono::duration::zero`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/zero)) to do so. They are also all comparable and equivalent:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <ratio>
int main() {
    static_assert((std::chrono::hours::zero() == std::chrono::nanoseconds::zero()) &&
                  (std::chrono::duration<short, std::nano>::zero() ==
                   std::chrono::duration<int, std::deci>::zero()) &&
                  (std::chrono::duration<short, std::deca>::zero() ==
                   std::chrono::duration<long, std::exa>::zero()) &&
                  (std::chrono::duration<long, std::atto>::zero().count() ==
                   std::chrono::duration<float, std::exa>::zero().count()));
// This compiles.
}
```

Example from the function link above.

From there, which one to use is not something of function, but opinion. I would suggest that since you have chosen `std::chrono::seconds` as the type of `start` and `end` that you should use `std::chrono::seconds::zero()` to keep it consistent. But this is simply my opinion.

If you have access to chrono literals (c++14) then the suggestion from @HowardHinnant is even more concise:

```
using namespace std::chrono_literals; // Somewhere in your cpp
...
if (end - start == 0s) {
```

Comment: In my project, I have many `std::chrono::seconds` and `std::chrono::milliseconds` and in many functions I need to check if some of them equals to zero or not. For now I'm always worrying about if I used the right zero... So it seems that I can simply use one zero, such as `std::chrono::seconds::zero()`.

Comment: Yeah, I understand. I may write a template function `boo isZero(...)` with the specification `std::chrono::seconds` and `std::chrono::milliseconds`.

Comment: `x == 0s` is pretty concise and works as good as anything else.

Comment: @HowardHinnant requires `using namespace std::chrono_literals;` but that sounds good to me.

Comment: @HowardHinnant Well, I'd like to use `0s` but I have to work with c11, not 14...

Comment: Then `0_s`, with your own UDL.